# On Windows 10/11, change system settings via command line (either PowerShell or CMD) without opening Settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

Title is pretty straightforward, but some background to help elaborate; I'm attempting to, in Godot Engine, create a "desktop environment" of sorts for Windows -- think the ages of Microsoft Bob in a way, exception being the fact this still looks like a desktop and not a living room.

While my concept is going good thus far (making my own "programs", being able to launch other programs outside the environment, etc.) I've realized that it may not be possible to include a proper "settings" window or program if I can't manipulate the settings of the Windows system itself, e.g. time, without being able to do so from the command line.

I know certain settings (again, e.g. time) have their own CMD or PowerShell counterparts (DATE/TIME for CMD, Get/Set-Date/Time for PowerShell) and have had them since before Settings (and in the case of CMD, Control Panel) was truly a thing, but there are others (e.g. Bluetooth, app notifications, focus assist, etc.) that I'm not entirely sure about.

Is there a way I can manage almost all essential settings to Windows that will matter without needing to open the Settings app via `start ms-settings:`? Or do I *have* to go through Settings for most things now? I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/965237/change-windows-settings-via-code) that asks similar, but all the answers are only pointing towards the example of *services*, which isn't what I'm looking for.

**Edit:** It came to my attention that there are a few issues that I didn't go over, so allow me to clarify a few things;

1. In order for Godot Engine to manage the system, it can issue commands as if it were a command line. Thus, I want to know if essential settings can be changed via either PowerShell or CMD.
2. On the topic of "essential"; I basically want the user to be able to modify most settings (bar a few mentions) not directly tied to personalization, since I can handle that in Godot itself (i.e., I don't need anything from the Personalization or Accessibility section of Settings).

In essence, I want to replicate these sections of Settings;

- System, with exceptions to things involving remote connection or notifications, since that would supersede the game regardless,
- Devices, except "Pen & Windows Ink" since I doubt tablet pens are compatible (or, at least, well-supported) by Godot Engine,
- Apps,
- Accounts,
- Search,
- Privacy,
- Update & Security,
- Time & Language,
- Network & Internet.

I want the user to be able to change settings of Windows like they would normally, just through my environment I'm creating.

Comment: I hadn't considered that! Let me update my question to be a little more clear.

Comment: I believe that you will need to address each one of these requirements differently and I doubt very seriously that you will be able to do all of them from a command prompt.  Technically, there is very little that you can't do from Powershell.. but in application, you will be issuing "hacks" for most of the functionality.  As far as I can tell.. Microsoft is guarded in releasing the API to control settings (if there is an API at all).  I don't mean to discourage you.. but I have been a windows programmer for over 25 years.

Comment: Since most, if not all, of these setting are maintained in the Registry, you might make scripts to update each field in the Registry. Use a tool such as RegistryChangesView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html, to see what changes occur when you make manual changes, and create a template for the text of the .reg file accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS Settings app is an amalgamation of many different internal windows tools and APIs, which can make your overall goal pretty difficult.

The **only** real catch-all solution is that these functions are are centrally documented for C++ as the [Windows API list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list) (Formerly called the Win32 API), and they aren't simple plug and play functions.

While they do take some work to get functional, you can often find examples or tools that other people have built to go from, and most of the simpler functions haven't changed in decades

---

That said, here are some examples of other ways you might manage a simple setting like default printer:

- In C++, using the windows API docs [SetDefaultPrinter()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setdefaultprinter) like above
- Powershell has native commands to manage printers in the `PrintManagement` module, but many community modules can be found and re-used for functions that PS is missing by default
- Old command-line functions like `RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n PrinterName`
- Via registry settings like: `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\  Device=\\Server\PrinterName`
- Or various third-party tools that wrap one of the above functions

Most settings will have some combination of the above available to you.

---

One suggestion that I've seen other software do is utilize [ms-settings URIs](https://4sysops.com/wiki/list-of-ms-settings-uri-commands-to-open-specific-settings-in-windows-10/history/?revision=1558411) to bring someone directly to the place they need to change a setting, though it would display outside godot